# How do i color a specific text in a specific item/s in a ListBox?

Tags: c#

I tried this code but its not working:

```
private void LoadKeys(Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {

               string line = System.String.Empty;
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(keywords))
               {
                   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                       dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                       listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem(Color.Green, "Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]));
                   }
               }

        }
```

Now the class MyListBoxItem:

```
public class MyListBoxItem 
        {
            public MyListBoxItem(Color c, string m)
            {
                ItemColor = c; Message = m;
            }
            public Color ItemColor
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Message
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

And the listBox1_DrawItem event:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            MyListBoxItem item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as MyListBoxItem;
            // Get the current item and cast it to MyListBoxItem
            if (item != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString( // Draw the appropriate text in the ListBox
                    item.Message, // The message linked to the item
                    listBox1.Font, // Take the font from the listbox
                    new SolidBrush(item.ItemColor), // Set the color
                    0, // X pixel coordinate
                    e.Index * listBox1.ItemHeight // Y pixel coordinate.  Multiply the index by the ItemHeight defined in the listbox.
                );
            }
            else
            {
                // The item isn't a MyListBoxItem, do something about it
            } 
        }
```

In the ListBox before trying this with the colors and draw item i used this line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
```

The result was for example: Url: http://www.google.com --- Localy KeyWord: google

Now when trying to color it this line in Green the color is still black and the text in the listBox is now:

GatherLinks.Form1+MyListBoxItem         strange.

What i wanted ot do is to color in the first line in the listBox the Url: in Red the --- in blue and the localykeyword: in yellow
In the second line the Url: in Green the --- in Red and the value for example google in Blue.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Switching to a ListView with ViewMode=Details will allow you to specify foreground and background colors for every item in the list. Let me know if this is acceptable and I will change this comment in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this in one of my projects.  As per Turnkey above I have the lines:

```
 tasksListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
  tasksListBox.DrawItem += listBox_DrawItem;
```

In the initialization code of my form.  The code for DrawItem  deals with things like the selection color

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == -1)
            {
                return;
            }

            e.DrawBackground();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            var selected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
            var lb = (ListBox)sender;

            if (selected)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue), e.Bounds);
                g.DrawString(lb.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.White), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
                return;
            }

            var item = (ProjectToDoRecord)lb.Items[e.Index];
            var textColor = item.TrafficLight();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
            g.DrawString(lb.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(textColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
```

The color of each item drawn is determined by textColor.  This is set to a color defined in the item being drawn.

Comment: Scruffyduck and how do i use it in the code after it to color the specific text part in each line in different color ? please show me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the DrawMode property of the list box to allow owner drawing?

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

Comment: Turnkey its working but its painting the whole line/s and not a selected text. For example if i change the line to : listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem(Color.Red, "Url: ")); it will color all the lines with Url: to Red. Wich is not what i wanted. I wanted to color one line in another color and also each part of the text in each line in another color.

Comment: I think that is a limitation of the ListBox control itself to paint by item.